# Angular - Data is loaded - Initial value of ID is NaN

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, asynchronous

On my web-app written in angular I am **posting data to a Database** and I am **displaying this data in a table** on the same `html`. Each data record has an **ID**. And every time I am adding new data, the ID is going to be increased. The first input field shows the actual ID, see the screenshot below:
[image]

In my `ngOnInit`-method I am initialising the id and I call the function `fbGetData()` in order to display the data.

But now I am facing one odd **problem**:

Everytime I starting the application the initial value which is displayed in the ID-field is `NaN`. 
[image]

Obviously I cannot post any data to the database because the ID is not a number. So I have to switch to another page on my application and then switch back. After that the correct ID is displayed. I also tried to move my methods from the `ngOnInit`-method to the constructor but this didn't help.

Somehow I think that I need to **implement** the **methods asynchronously**, but I have no idea how to do this, since I am quite new to *Angular/Typscript*.

I hope you guys can help me with this problem or give me any hint or idea.
I appreciate your answers!

Here is my `.ts` Code:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { rootRoute } from '@angular/router/src/router_module';
import { SearchNamePipe } from '../search-name.pipe';
import { LoginComponent } from '../login/login.component';
import {NavbarService} from '../navbar.service';

declare var firebase: any;
const d: Date = new Date();

@Component({
  selector: 'app-business-function',
  templateUrl: './business-function.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./business-function.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  providers: [DataService, SearchNamePipe, LoginComponent]
})

export class BusinessFunctionComponent implements OnInit {
  id;
  name: String;
  descr: String;
  typ: String;
  bprocess: String;
  appsystem: String;
  applications: String;
  datum: String;
  liste = [];
  bprocessliste = [];
  applicationliste = [];
  appsystemliste = [];
  isDesc: boolean = false;
  column: String = 'Name';
  direction: number;
  loginName: String;
  statusForm: Boolean = false;

  private idlist = [];

  constructor(
    private dataService: DataService,
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private searchName: SearchNamePipe,
    private navbarService: NavbarService
    ) {

    this.datum = Date().toString();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.navbarService.show(); 
    firebase.database().ref().child('/AllID/').
    on('child_added', (snapshot) => {
      this.idlist.push(snapshot.val()
    )})
    this.id = this.idlist[0];
    console.log("ID: "+this.id);
    console.log("IDlist: "+this.idlist[0]);
    this.id++;
    console.log("ID: "+this.id);
    this.fbGetData();
  }

  fbGetData() {
    firebase.database().ref().child('/BFunctions/').orderByChild('CFlag').equalTo('active').
      on('child_added', (snapshot) => {
        //firebase.database().ref('/BFunctions/').orderByKey().on('child_added', (snapshot) => {
        // alter code ... neuer Code nimmt nur die Validen mit dem X Flag    
        this.liste.push(snapshot.val())
      });

    // firebase.database().ref().child('/ID/').on('child_added', (snapshot) => { 

    //Bprocess DB Zugriff
    firebase.database().ref().child('/BProcess/').orderByChild('CFlag').equalTo('active').
      on('child_added', (snapshot) => {

        this.bprocessliste.push(snapshot.val())
      });

    //Appsystem DB Zugriff
    firebase.database().ref().child('/Appsystem/').orderByChild('CFlag').equalTo('active').
      on('child_added', (snapshot) => {
        this.applicationliste.push(snapshot.val())
      })

    //Application DB Zugriff
    firebase.database().ref().child('/Application/').orderByChild('CFlag').equalTo('active').
      on('child_added', (snapshot) => {

        this.applicationliste.push(snapshot.val())
      });
    console.log(this.applicationliste);
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to update the `id` inside your callback:

```
firebase.database().ref().child('/AllID/').on('child_added', (snapshot) => {
    this.idlist.push(snapshot.val())

    this.id = this.idlist[0];
    console.log("ID: "+this.id);
    console.log("IDlist: "+this.idlist[0]);
    this.id++;
    console.log("ID: "+this.id);
    this.fbGetData();
})
```

Otherwise `id` retains it initial `undefined` value. This is because the call to firebase is asynchronous.

Here is what happens in your original code:

1. call to firebase API... wait your response
2. set `id` to `this.idlist[0]`, which is empty (undefined)
3. ...some time later, getting response from firebase
4. `id` does not get updated because the code in point 2. has already been executed.

Anything that you need to do when you get the result from an asynchronous call, must be executed inside the callback function.